# How to Share youtube link in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to post youtube link in laravel 
My controller

```
 if($validator->fails())
            {
                $userStatus = new Status();
                $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
                $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $userStatus -> save();

                Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
                return redirect(route('class'));
```

Now i can post a status. But in my status i also want to post a youtube link.

[If i post a youtube link its looks like status.what should i do now. how can i define a link in my project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0oB1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you must put your anchor tag inside `{!! !!}` in your blade.

E.g.

```
{!!<a href="http://linktoyoutube">youtube video</a>!!}
```

Comment: yes sir i also tried this. but i need to view status also. if user post status its need to look status. and if user post a link its needs to look link..

Comment: You can use <a href="https://github.com/SoapBox/linkifyjs">linkify</a> to convert plain text url to hyperlink before posting to the server in jquery and  do not forget to escape.

Comment: That's a javascript plugin, yes you can